# как в вызов свойства объекта передать значиние переменной

Tags: php

Есть 2 json

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Lsp_PD] => Условия передачи информации Лимиты
    [Asp_PD] => Условия передачи информации
)
```

и

```
stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => Asp_PD
            [status] => 2
            [date] => 2022-01-28 12:37:56
            [techId] => 
            [print_form] => 
            [description] => 
        )
```

как можно проверить существует ли значение $json2->type в $json1
пытался так

```
if (!empty($json1->$json2->type)){
return true;
}
```

не работает. Как быть?

Comment: в 1 json  естественно несколько значений например так stdClass Object
(
    [Lsp_PD] => Условия передачи информации Лимиты, [Asp_PD] => Условия передачи информации
)

Comment: `var_dump($json1->{$json2->type});`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php